# Building a Json Format for a Case Class with Abstract Members

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I am using the Play Framework and trying to build JSON validator for a class with abstract members. Shown below, the DataSource class is the base class which I am trying to validate the format against.

```
// SourceTypeConfig Trait.

trait SourceTypeConfig

  final case class RDBMSConfig(...) extends SourceTypeConfig
  object RDBMSConfig { implicit val fmt = Json.format[RDBMSConfig] }

  final case class DirectoryConfig(
      path: String,
      pathType: String // Local, gcloud, azure, aws, etc.
  ) extends SourceTypeConfig
  object DirectoryConfig { implicit val fmt = Json.format[DirectoryConfig] }

// FormatConfig trait.

trait FormatConfig

  final case class SQLConfig(...) extends FormatConfig
  object SQLConfig { implicit val fmt = Json.format[SQLConfig]}

  final case class CSVConfig(
      header: String,
      inferSchema: String,
      delimiter: String
  ) extends FormatConfig
  object CSVConfig { implicit val fmt = Json.format[CSVConfig]}


// DataSource base class.
case class DataSource(
      name: String,
      sourceType: String,
      sourceTypeConfig: SourceTypeConfig,
      format: String,
      formatConfig: FormatConfig
  )
```

What I am hoping to accomplish:

```
val input: JsValue = Json.parse(
      """
        {
        "name" : "test1",
        "sourceType" : "directory",
        "sourceTypeConfig" : {"path" : "gs://test/path", "pathType" "google"},
        "format" : "csv",
        "formatConfig" : {"header" : "yes", "inferSchema" : "yes",  "delimiter" :  "|"}
        }
      """
    )

    val inputResult = input.validate[DataSource]
```

What I am struggling with is building the DataSource object and defining its reads/writes/format. I would like it to contain a match based on the `sourceType` and `format` values that direct it to point towards the associated `sourceTypeConfig` and `formatConfig`'s formats so it can parse out the JSON.

Comment: Recent Play JSON releases support *sealed* trait (or trait with `apply`/`unapply` in companion)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of building a parser at the `DataSource` level, I defined parsers at the `SourceConfig` and `FormatConfig` levels, similar to what is shown below.

```
sealed trait SourceConfig{val sourceType: String}
object SourceConfig{
  implicit val fmt = new Format[SourceConfig] {
    def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[SourceConfig] = {
      def from(sourceType: String, data: JsObject): JsResult[SourceConfig] = sourceType match {
        case "RDBMS"     => Json.fromJson[RDBMSConfig](data)(RDBMSConfig.fmt)
        case "directory" => Json.fromJson[DirectoryConfig](data)(DirectoryConfig.fmt)
        case _           => JsError(s"Unknown source type: '$sourceType'")
      }

      for {
        sourceType <- (json \ "sourceType").validate[String]
        data       <- json.validate[JsObject]
        result     <- from(sourceType, data)
      } yield result
    }

    def writes(source: SourceConfig): JsValue =
      source match {
        case b: RDBMSConfig     => Json.toJson(b)(RDBMSConfig.fmt)
        case b: DirectoryConfig => Json.toJson(b)(DirectoryConfig.fmt)
      }
  }
}
```

Then, `DataSource` could be simply defined as:

```
object DataSource { implicit val fmt = Json.format[DataSource] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `play-json-derived-codecs` library:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.julienrf" %% "play-json-derived-codecs" % "4.0.0"

import julienrf.json.derived.flat

implicit val format1: OFormat[RDBMSConfig] = Json.format[RDBMSConfig]
implicit val format2: OFormat[DirectoryConfig] = Json.format[DirectoryConfig]
implicit val format3: OFormat[SourceTypeConfig] = flat.oformat((__ \ "sourceType").format[String])
```